# Disappearing usernames in comments

Tags: support, comments

I am facing a pretty weird bug. Sometime, when I type an '@username' at the start of a comment, it disappears when I submit the comment. If I afterwards click on edit, the '@username' is not present in the comment text body either.

Specific instance occured in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/scifi-episode-where-one-of-the-crew-members-becomes-a-monster). Putting in another comment had the same bug. This has occured before, but I though it was just a freak accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was the username the person that wrote the question/answer that you're commenting on?  I've seen this recently as well.  My guess is that it is a new feature where the username is removed because it's implied.

(Personally, I think explicit is better than implicit, but I suppose there is some merit in this).

Comment: correct, the post owner is always notified of all comments so `@postowner` is never required. We auto-remove it if the only people commenting are you and the post owner. (protip: @username is also not required for post owner response comments in the same situation.. we assume the post owner is never talking to him or herself...)